# cannot read part-00000 (MapReduce output)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I'm trying to read the results of my map-reduce functions which is configured to be in an Avro format - but I can't.

The head of the part-00000 file looks like that:

0        Objavro.codenullavro.schema�G{
37              "type": "record",
59              "name": "xxx",
82              "fields": [
98                     {
108                        "name": "aaa",
141                        "type": [
163                            "string",
189                            "null"
212                                   ]
226                       },
.
.
.

and so on.. (**the left numbers are in the file!!**).

How can I read this file?

Answer (score 0):

There are utilities like [avrocat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/avrocat/0.4.2) and avropipe.
`avrocat` outputs each record in an Avro file on a single line, using the JSON encoding defined by the [Avro spec](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#json_encoding).  `avropipe` produces a separate line for each 'field' in each record; its output is (roughly speaking) what you'd get from piping the JSON encoding of each record through the [jsonpipe](https://github.com/dvxhouse/jsonpipe) tool.

ref: http://apache-avro.679487.n3.nabble.com/Getting-started-with-Avro-Reading-from-an-Avro-formatted-file-td3685069.html

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not about regular Avro file. My question is about the part-00000 file as an output of mapreduce job with a number on the left side of each line..

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to read this manually? Download the the avro-tools Jar at https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/avro/ in `.../java/avro-#.#.#/avro-tools-#.#.#.jar` and then run:

`java -jar avro-tools-*.jar tojson part-00000.avro > part-00000-converted.json`

If you have a valid Avro output, the json file should contain the objects stored in part-00000.avro.